# Android OBD Reader not going through all switch cases

Tags: android, switch-statement, obd-ii

I am working on a Android app that modifies the Bluetooth Chat example given with Eclipse to create an On-Board Diagnostic (OBD) reader.  My code sends a message to my vehicle's ECU and retrieves data with the use of switches.

Now, my problem is, for some reason when I run my program I only receive data for 6 of my cases and I am not receiving data for the rest of them.

The code is kind of lengthy.

```
    public void startTransmission() {

        sendMessage("01 00" + '\r');

    }

    public void getData(int messagenumber) {

        final TextView TX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TXView2);

        switch (messagenumber) {

        case 1:
            sendMessage("01 0C" + '\r'); // get RPM
            TX.setText("01 0C");
            messagenumber++;
            break;

        case 2:
            sendMessage("01 0D" + '\r'); // get MPH
            TX.setText("01 0D");
            messagenumber++;
            break;
        case 3:
            sendMessage("01 04" + '\r'); // get Engine Load
            TX.setText("01 04");
            messagenumber++;
            break;
        case 4:
            sendMessage("01 05" + '\r'); // get Coolant Temperature
            TX.setText("01 05");
            messagenumber++;
            break;
        case 5:
            sendMessage("01 0F" + '\r'); // get Intake Temperature
            TX.setText("01 0F");
            messagenumber++;
            break;

        case 6:
            sendMessage("AT RV" + '\r'); // get Voltage
            TX.setText("AT RV");
            messagenumber++;
            break;

        case 7:
            sendMessage("01 06" + '\r'); // get Fuel Trim Bank 1 Sensor 1
            TX.setText("01 06");
            messagenumber++;

        case 8:
            sendMessage("01 07" + '\r'); // get Fuel Trim Bank 1 Sensor 2
            TX.setText("01 07");
            messagenumber++;

        case 9:
            sendMessage("01 0B" + '\r'); // get Intake Manifold Pressure
            TX.setText("01 0B");
            messagenumber++;

        case 10:
            sendMessage("01 0E" + '\r'); // get Timing Advance
            TX.setText("01 0E");
            messagenumber++;

        case 11:
            sendMessage("01 11" + '\r'); // get Throttle Position
            TX.setText("01 11");
            messagenumber++;

        case 12:
            sendMessage("01 14" + '\r'); // get Oxygen Bank 1 Sensor 1
            TX.setText("01 14");
            messagenumber++;

        case 13:
            sendMessage("01 15" + '\r'); // get Oxygen Bank 1 Sensor 2
            TX.setText("01 15");
            messagenumber++;

        default:
            ;
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
        if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return;
        }// end if

        // Check that there's actually something to send
        if (message.length() > 0) {
            // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
            byte[] send = message.getBytes();
            mChatService.write(send);

            // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
            mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
            // mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
        }// end if
    }// end sendMessage method    

    // The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            // <--------- Initialize Data Display Fields ---------->//
            /* PID = 0C */final TextView RPM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numRPM);
            /* PID = 0D */final TextView MPH = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numSpeed);
            /* PID = 04 */final TextView engineLoad = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numLoad);
            /* PID = 05 */final TextView coolantTemperature = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numCoolant);
            /* PID = 0F */final TextView intakeTemperature = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numIntakeAir);
            /* PID = RV */final TextView voltage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numVoltage);
            /* PID = 06 */final TextView fuelTrimB1S1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numFTb1s1);
            /* PID = 07 */final TextView fuelTrimB1S2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numFTb1s2);
            /* PID = 0A */final TextView intakeManifold = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numManifold);
            /* PID = 0E */final TextView timingAdvance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numTiming);
            /* PID = 11 */final TextView throttlePos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numThrottle);
            /* PID = 14 */final TextView oxygenB1s1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numO2b1s1);
            /* PID = 15 */final TextView oxygenB1s2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numO2b1s2);
            /* displays recieved string */final TextView RX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RXView2);

            String dataRecieved;
            int value = 0;
            int value2 = 0;
            int PID = 0;

            switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                if (D)
                    Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to,
                            mConnectedDeviceName));
                    mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                    break;
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    setStatus(R.string.title_connecting);
                    break;
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
                case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                    setStatus(R.string.title_not_connected);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                // byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the buffer
                // String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);

                // mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

                // ------- ADDED CODE FOR OBD -------- //
                dataRecieved = readMessage;
                RX.setText(dataRecieved);

                if ((dataRecieved != null)
                        && (dataRecieved
                                .matches("\\s*[0-9A-Fa-f]{2} [0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\\s*\r?\n?"))) {

                    dataRecieved = dataRecieved.trim();
                    String[] bytes = dataRecieved.split(" ");

                    if ((bytes[0] != null) && (bytes[1] != null)) {

                        PID = Integer.parseInt(bytes[0].trim(), 16);
                        value = Integer.parseInt(bytes[1].trim(), 16);
                    }

                    switch (PID) {

                    case 15:// PID(0F): Intake Temperature

                        value = value - 40; // Formula for Intake Temperature
                        value = ((value * 9) / 5) + 32; // Convert from Celsius
                                                        // to Farenheit
                        String displayIntakeTemp = String.valueOf(value);
                        intakeTemperature.setText(displayIntakeTemp + " F");

                        break;
                    // end Intake Temperature case

                    case 4:// PID(04): Engine Load

                        value = (value * 100) / 255;

                        String displayEngineLoad = String.valueOf(value);
                        engineLoad.setText(displayEngineLoad + " %");
                        break;
                    // end Engine Load case

                    case 5:// PID(05): Coolant Temperature

                        value = value - 40;
                        value = ((value * 9) / 5) + 32; // convert to deg F

                        String displayCoolantTemp = String.valueOf(value);
                        coolantTemperature.setText(displayCoolantTemp);
                        break;
                    // end Coolant Temperature case

                    case 12: // PID(0C): RPM
                        int RPM_value = (value * 256) / 4;

                        String displayRPM = String.valueOf(RPM_value);
                        RPM.setText(displayRPM);
                        break;
                    // end RPM case

                    case 13:// PID(0D): MPH

                        value = (value * 5) / 8; // convert KPH to MPH

                        String displayMPH = String.valueOf(value);
                        MPH.setText(displayMPH + " MPH");
                        break;
                    // end MPH case

                    case 6:// PID(06): Fuel Trim Bank 1 Sensor 1

                        value = (value - 128) * 100 / 128;

                        String displayFtB1s1 = String.valueOf(value);
                        fuelTrimB1S1.setText(displayFtB1s1);
                        break;

                    case 7:// PID(07): Fuel Trim Bank 1 Sensor 2

                        value = (value - 128) * 100 / 128;

                        String displayFtB1s2 = String.valueOf(value);
                        fuelTrimB1S2.setText(displayFtB1s2);
                        break;

                    case 11: // PID(0A): Intake Manifold Pressure

                        String displayIntakeManifold = String.valueOf(value);
                        intakeManifold.setText(displayIntakeManifold);
                        break;

                    case 14: // PID(0E): Timing Advance

                        value = value / 2 - 64;

                        String displayTimingAdvance = String.valueOf(value);
                        timingAdvance.setText(displayTimingAdvance);
                        break;

                    case 17: // PID(11): Throttle Position

                        value = value * 100 / 255;

                        String displayThrottlePos = String.valueOf(value);
                        throttlePos.setText(displayThrottlePos);

                    case 20: // PID(14): Oxygen Bank 1 Sensor 1

                        String displayO2B1s1 = String.valueOf(value);
                        oxygenB1s1.setText(displayO2B1s1);
                        break;

                    case 21: // PID(14): Oxygen Bank 1 Sensor 2

                        String displayO2B1s2 = String.valueOf(value);
                        oxygenB1s2.setText(displayO2B1s2);
                        break;

                    default:
                        ;

                    }

                } else if ((dataRecieved != null)
                        && (dataRecieved
                                .matches("\\s*[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2} [0-9A-Fa-f]{2} [0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\\s*\r?\n?"))) {

                    dataRecieved = dataRecieved.trim();
                    String[] bytes = dataRecieved.split(" ");

                    if ((bytes[0] != null) && (bytes[1] != null)
                            && (bytes[2] != null)) {

                        PID = Integer.parseInt(bytes[0].trim(), 16);
                        value = Integer.parseInt(bytes[1].trim(), 16);
                        value2 = Integer.parseInt(bytes[2].trim(), 16);
                    }

                    // PID(0C): RPM
                    if (PID == 12) {

                        int RPM_value = ((value * 256) + value2) / 4;

                        String displayRPM = String.valueOf(RPM_value);
                        RPM.setText(displayRPM + " RPM");
                    } else if ((PID == 1) || (PID == 65)) {

                        switch (value) {

                        case 15:// PID(0F): Intake Temperature

                            value2 = value2 - 40; // formula for INTAKE AIR TEMP
                            value2 = ((value2 * 9) / 5) + 32; // convert to deg
                                                                // F

                            String displayIntakeTemp = String.valueOf(value2);
                            intakeTemperature
                                    .setText(displayIntakeTemp + " °F");
                            break;
                        // end Intake Temperature case

                        case 4:// PID(04): Engine Load

                            value2 = (value2 * 100) / 255;
                            String displayEngineLoad = String.valueOf(value2);

                            engineLoad.setText(displayEngineLoad + " %");
                            break;
                        // end Engine Load case

                        case 5:// PID(05): Coolant Temperature

                            value2 = value2 - 40;
                            value2 = ((value2 * 9) / 5) + 32; // convert to deg
                                                                // F

                            String displayCoolantTemp = String.valueOf(value2);
                            coolantTemperature.setText(displayCoolantTemp
                                    + " °F");
                            break;

                        case 13:// PID(0D): MPH

                            value2 = (value2 * 5) / 8; // convert to MPH

                            String displayMPH = String.valueOf(value2);
                            MPH.setText(displayMPH + " MPH");
                            break;

//                      case 6:// PID(06): Fuel Trim Bank 1 Sensor 1
//
//                          value = (value - 128) * 100 / 128;
//
//                          String displayFtB1s1 = String.valueOf(value);
//                          fuelTrimB1S1.setText(displayFtB1s1 + " V");
//                          break;
//
//                      case 7:// PID(07): Fuel Trim Bank 1 Sensor 2
//
//                          value = (value - 128) * 100 / 128;
//
//                          String displayFtB1s2 = String.valueOf(value);
//                          fuelTrimB1S2.setText(displayFtB1s2 + " V");
//                          break;
//
//                      case 11: // PID(0A): Intake Manifold Pressure
//
//                          String displayIntakeManifold = String
//                                  .valueOf(value);
//                          intakeManifold.setText(displayIntakeManifold
//                                  + " psi");
//                          break;
//
//                      case 14: // PID(0E): Timing Advance
//
//                          value = value / 2 - 64;
//
//                          String displayTimingAdvance = String.valueOf(value);
//                          timingAdvance.setText(displayTimingAdvance + " °");
//                          break;
//
//                      case 17: // PID(11): Throttle Position
//
//                          value = value * 100 / 255;
//
//                          String displayThrottlePos = String.valueOf(value);
//                          throttlePos.setText(displayThrottlePos + " %");
//
//                      case 20: // PID(14): Oxygen Bank 1 Sensor 1
//
//                          String displayO2B1s1 = String.valueOf(value);
//                          oxygenB1s1.setText(displayO2B1s1 + " V");
//                          break;
//
//                      case 21: // PID(14): Oxygen Bank 1 Sensor 2
//
//                          String displayO2B1s2 = String.valueOf(value);
//                          oxygenB1s2.setText(displayO2B1s2 + " V");
//                          break;

                        default:
                            ;
                        }
                    }

                } else if ((dataRecieved != null)
                        && (dataRecieved
                                .matches("\\s*[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]?)?V\\s*\r*\n*"))) {

                    dataRecieved = dataRecieved.trim();
                    voltage.setText(dataRecieved);

                } else if ((dataRecieved != null)
                        && (dataRecieved
                                .matches("\\s*[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]?)?V\\s*V\\s*>\\s*\r*\n*"))) {

                    dataRecieved = dataRecieved.trim();
                    // String volt_number = dataRecieved.substring(0,
                    // dataRecieved.length() - 1);

                    voltage.setText(dataRecieved);

                } else if ((dataRecieved != null)
                        && (dataRecieved
                                .matches("\\s*[ .A-Za-z0-9\\?*>\r\n]*\\s*>\\s*\r*\n*"))) {

                    if (message_number == 7)
                        message_number = 1;
                    getData(message_number++);
                }

                break;
    }
}
```

Where I think I want to focus on is:

```
if ((dataRecieved != null)
                        && (dataRecieved
                                .matches("\\s*[0-9A-Fa-f]{2} [0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\\s*\r?\n?"))) {

                    dataRecieved = dataRecieved.trim();
                    String[] bytes = dataRecieved.split(" ");

                    if ((bytes[0] != null) && (bytes[1] != null)) {

                        PID = Integer.parseInt(bytes[0].trim(), 16);
                        value = Integer.parseInt(bytes[1].trim(), 16);
                    }
```

This code is based off some research that I have done and I am not sure what the string behind the dataRecieved.matches is.  It looks to be an array and I am thinking that the parameters received are causing my switch cases not to fire.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: dont post the entire code, post some problem code where we can answer to the problem.

Comment: You forgot the `break` statements after case 6. Maybe that´s the problem?

Comment: Wow...ok I feel stupid. The `break` statements is what did it.  Thanks!!  And my apologies for the long code in the original.  I did cut it down to what I thought would be relevant.

Comment: Any ideas to what the string statement is behind the `dataRecieved.matches` is?

Comment: It returns a boolean if dataReceived mathces that regular expression.
It's basically a check if it matches:
<2 hexadecimal digits><space><2 hexadecimal numbers><\r\n>
Don know what \s* does though. The star means \s can show up zero or more times. I think it's for garbage strings, if you know what I mean.

Find more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression